# Fast calculation of normalization factor for normalized cross correlation

Tags: cross-correlation

There has been a number of posts here I've browsed through that explain implementations of normalized cross-correlation in Python. One such implementation that is frequently cited is found below.

```
def normxcorr2(template, image, mode="full"):
    
    template = template - np.mean(template)
    image = image - np.mean(image)

    a1 = np.ones(template.shape)
    # Faster to flip up down and left right then use fftconvolve instead of scipy's correlate
    ar = np.flipud(np.fliplr(template))
    out = fftconvolve(image, ar.conj(), mode=mode)
    
    image = fftconvolve(np.square(image), a1, mode=mode) - \
            np.square(fftconvolve(image, a1, mode=mode)) / (np.prod(template.shape))

    # Remove small machine precision errors after subtraction
    image[np.where(image < 0)] = 0

    template = np.sum(np.square(template))
    out = out / np.sqrt(image * template)

    # Remove any divisions by 0 or very close to 0
    out[np.where(np.logical_not(np.isfinite(out)))] = 0
    
    return out
```

https://github.com/Sabrewarrior/normxcorr2-python/blob/master/normxcorr2.py

My understanding is that the normalization term is the square root of the autocorrelation of the two input images.
\begin{equation}C=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(I(i)-\bar{I})(J(i)-\bar{J})}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(I(i)-\bar{I})^{2} \sum_{j=1}^{n}{(J(i)-\bar{J})^{2}}}}\end{equation}

for two images $I$ and $J$ respectively. I am having difficulty understanding this line:

```
image = fftconvolve(np.square(image), a1, mode=mode) - \
        np.square(fftconvolve(image, a1, mode=mode)) / (np.prod(template.shape))
```

Is this a clever way of calculating the autocorrelation of one of the input images? Why not take the autocorrelation like the 'template' image?

Comment: have you tried the method that you have suggested? is it bit-exact to the current method? you can compare the running time and figure out which is faster too. If it is faster, and provide the same results, you can probably improve the implementation, no?